# RetryableTopic - placeholder in attempts

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use ***@RetryableTopic*** with *custom naming strategy* for retry topic

The names Retry Topic are recorded in a separate in the class in the *List* field

```
@Data
@ConfigurationPropertis(value = "my.test")
public class TestConfig {

    private SubTest subTest = new SubTest();
    
    public static class SubTest {
        String strTopics ="FIRST, SECOND";
        List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strTopics.split(",")));
    }

}
```

I want to use *topics.size()* in ***@RetryableTopic*** in *attempts* as follows:

```
public class Test {

    private final TestConfig testConfig;

    @RetryableTopic(
        attempts ="#{testConfig.subTest.topics.size}",
        backoff = @Backoff(delay=1000),
        autoCreateTopics = "false")
    )
    @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic1",
    public void processMessage(MyPojo1 message) {
       // ... message processing
    }
}
```

**spel** not work, and I don't understand how to do it correctly

Comment: If you want to reference a bean you need to prefix it with `@` so something like `#{@testConfig.subTest.topics.size()}` you also need to specify the method else it will try to call the property which would be something like `getSize()` which doesn't exist. If that doesn't resolve it please include the error message you are receiving.

Comment: testConfig all the same, not announced as@Component, Service or Bean, I have: A component requered a bean named 'testConfig' that could not be found

Comment: See my answer; there is a special pseudo bean name `__listener` to get a reference to the current listener bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring for Apache Kafka has a special pseudo bean name for the current listener (`__listener` by default, but overridable on the annnotation).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-properties

So, you can use `"#{__listener.testConfig.subTest.topics.size()}"` but the fields must be public (or have public getters()).

The `@` prefix is not necessary.